# Update title of a webpart programmatically for a specific language

Tags: web-part

I want to update the title of a webpart programmatically for a specific language. I read it's possible with  "SPWeb.SupportedUICultures". Does anyone know how to do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are you creating the webpart? or is it a third party webpart or out of the box webpart?

Answer (score 2):

[Localizing SharePoint Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee696750.aspx) is quite a large topic and there is some great reference material on MSDN.

[SPWeb.SupportedUICultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.supporteduicultures.ASPX) is a method that will tell you which cultures are available in your web. The cultures should correspond with the Optional [Language Packs installed](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262108(v=office.15).aspx).

When I localizing a web part, I often start with [creating a resource file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231537.aspx) for each of the languages I can support. The resource files should contain all of the strings you want available in mutiple lanugages. For your example, given a resource file exists, instead of hardcoding the title name in the web part code, call [HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.getglobalresourceobject.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
The problem is that it is a webpart created from the Sharepoint user interface I'm trying to translate programmatically. When i save my site as template site, the labels are the same for all languages ​​(including the title of webparts) in a newer site created with this template. It is possible to translate the title of webparts from the Sharepoint interface for the language enabled, but I would do it by code via the activation of a feature. 
If it is possible to translate via the Sharepoint interface, i think is possible to do by code, but I can not find how.